# Sequential Methods?

Tags: java, android

How to create methods which can only be called after a particular method is called?

For e.g:
Glide, the Image Loading library has this method sequence like -

```
Glide.with(context)
     .asBitmap()
     .load(url)
     .into(imageView);
```

Here, we cannot call `asBitmap()` after `load(url)` or `into(imageView)` before `load(url)`, any ideas how this is done?

Comment: It's called a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) or fluent API. In your example, the methods that can be called in any given part of the sequence are determined by the return type of the previous method in the sequence.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "cannot call". If you want runtime checking, hold state which says which methods have been called, and check the state when then next method is called. If you want compile-time checking, you need to return a type from the previous method that provides the allowable methods, as Robbie said.

Comment: @AndyTurner What I mean by "cannot call" is if I try to call a method name Method3() before calling Method1(), then it should show an error like "Method3() not recognized", just like the Glide library

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sequence won't work if the return types are all `this`?

Answer (score 1):

Each of these methods returns *something*.

An object of some class. So, the very first thing would be to look at the signature of each method to determine what it is returning.

The type of the returned object then determines which methods can be further invoked.

If the methods all return the same type, then you can't have such checks at compile time. Then the implementation has to track such things at runtime and throw exceptions in case some contract about order is violated.